# Generating test report by Running Pickles UI against a Specflow test project using SpecRun unit test runner

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow, specrun, picklesdoc

When watching the video of using the Pickles UI from commandline, it is using the NUnit console runner to generate a TesResults.xml prior to using the PicklesUI.  The PicklesUI uses the TestResults.xml generated from the NUnit console runner to generate a neat report. The problem for me is that I am not using NUnit for my tests.  I am using Specflow for C# and main unit test runner I am using is 'SpecRun.'  My tests are written using Selenium.

My question is how can I use the PicklesUI to generate test results from a test run ran from within Visual Studio 2017 using SpecRun?

I also get these errors
[image]

Comment: Doesn't the documentation not help you: http://docs.picklesdoc.com/en/latest/IntegratingTestResultsFromSpecRun/ ?

Comment: Never see this. I think the problem is I am not understanding.  I know how to modify the report template, but how does PickesUI integrate with the report template modified. What are the steps to generate a unique report using Pickles UI now that the report template has been modified